# Census, households made up of couples (with or without children) born in the same place (dplyr way)

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am working on early 20th century  french census.
I work on households. Each house houseold has a household_chief (always on position 1). 
When a houseold is based on a couple, the wife is always on second position.

```
id_houseold<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4,4,4, 5, 5)
 members <- c("household_chief", "wife", "child", "child","household_chief", "wife", "household_chief", "household_chief", "wife", "child", "household_chief","child")
 birthplace<- c("Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Bordeaux",   "Nantes", "Paris", "Paris", "Nantes", "Nantes,", "Nantes")
data <- data.frame(id_houseold, members, birthplace)
```

I have made a sequence of position of members of each household :

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
group_by(id_houseold) %>% 
mutate(position_in_menage = 1:n())
data
```

Here is my result :

```
id_houseold members         birthplace position_in_menage
     <dbl> <fct>           <fct>                   <int>
1           1 household_chief Paris                       1
2           1 wife            Paris                       2
3           1 child           Paris                       3
4           1 child           Paris                       4
5           2 household_chief Paris                       1
6           2 wife            Bordeaux                    2
7           3 household_chief Nantes                      1
8           4 household_chief Paris                       1
9           4 wife            Paris                       2
10          4 child           Nantes                      3
11          5 household_chief Nantes,                     1
12          5 child           Nantes                      2
```

What I want to kwow using dplyr package :

which households are made up of couples (with or without children) born in the same place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach using `filter`,

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
 filter(members %in% c("household_chief", "wife")) %>% 
 group_by(id_houseold) %>% 
 filter(n_distinct(birthplace) == 1 & n() > 1)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
> # Groups:   id_houseold [2]
>   id_houseold members         birthplace
>         <dbl> <fct>           <fct>     
> 1           1 household_chief Paris     
> 2           1 wife            Paris     
> 3           4 household_chief Paris     
> 4           4 wife            Paris
> ```

Comment: Your way is the cleanest way.

Comment: aghh...ok.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could check for each `id_houseold` if `"household_chief"` and `"wife"` are always present and if they share the same unique `birthplace` using `n_distinct`. If they share the same `birthplace` then `n_distinct` value would be 1.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id_houseold) %>%
  summarise(is_couple = all(c("household_chief", "wife") %in% members) &
            n_distinct(birthplace[members %in% c("household_chief", "wife")]) == 1))

#  id_houseold is_couple
#        <dbl> <lgl>    
#1           1 TRUE     
#2           2 FALSE     
#3           3 FALSE    
#4           4 TRUE     
#5           5 FALSE
```